# A word or phrase that describes a person who is a corporate employee with a very demanding work schedule, but keeps positive and optimistic

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, chinese

Recently, the word “打工人” has become a buzzword in China. It refers to a person who is a corporate employee – or anyone who works very hard only to earn a low or middle income – but who is still optimistic about life. That might sound weird, but it actually happens in China.

I hope to find a word or phrase to describe them. Thanks very much for your kindness and help.

Comment: We have things like ***wage-slaves*** and ***working stiffs*** in the West, but such people are at best *resigned* to their lot in life - hardly "optimistic". Maybe [***stoic***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/stoic), but that's also more about "not being *unhappy*" rather than actually being *happy*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "打工人" literally means an employed worker, and years ago it referred to the migrant worker. When describing themselves as a "打工人", Chinese people, especially the young generation, mean that they are tired of work or assignment but they have no choice, and they hope to encourage themselves.

Comment: Do people think the 打工人 is foolish? or noble? or stoic?

Comment: In the current social and cultural context, 打工人 is worth respect.

Comment: "Beating workers"?

Comment: I wonder if "dedicated employee" wouldn't be the closest fit.

Comment: "Dedicated employee" is acceptable, but it may not contain the meaning of being tired and having no choice.

Comment: It sounds like a subclass of those who've "drunk the Kool-Aid", those who accept a dangerous or destructive course on the basis of promised future rewards (rewards that most impartial people regard with skepticism). It's often used of those who've signed up to a corporate identity and subjugated their personal needs to those of the organisation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of one word that covers your definition. There are two that almost do the job and, if taken together, cover it well.

> Stakhanovite = An exceptionally hard-working or zealous person
>
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stakhanovite)

> it may be an adjective: of or relating to a Stakhanovite or to Stakhanovism.
>
> [dictionary online](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stakhanovite)

> Pollyanna = a person characterized by irrepressible optimism and a tendency to find good in everything
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Pollyanna)

> Pollyannaism = blind or excessive optimism, after the character Pollyanna, created by American writer Eleanor Porter (1868-1920).
>
> [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pollyannaism)

If I had to choose one of these it would be a *Pollyanna*, because the word certainly covers the unquestioning optimism, and the tendency "to find good in everything" would also apply to hard work. Or a Stakanovite Pollyanna would be such a person as you define.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 打工人 is a *stoic*. The Wikipedia entry on [Stoicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoicism) describes this Hellenistic philosophy:

> According to its teachings, as social beings, the path to *eudaimonia* (**happiness**, or **blessedness**) is found in accepting the moment as it presents itself, by **not allowing oneself to be controlled by** the desire for pleasure or by the **fear of pain**, by using one's mind to understand the world and to do one's part in nature's plan, and by working together and treating others fairly and justly.

[Eudaimonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudaimonia) is:

> a Greek word commonly translated as 'happiness' or 'welfare'; however, more accurate translations have been proposed to be 'human flourishing, prosperity' and 'blessedness'.

The stoic will therefore "soldier on" through pain, and is accorded respect by his peers.

Comment: I heard a podcast from The Happiness Lab on stoics: https://www.happinesslab.fm/happiness-lessons-of-the-ancients/episode-3-the-stoics that explains much of the philosophy. And here is a mention of James Stockdale, who was shot down over Vietnam, who endured much because of his Stoicism: https://dailystoic.com/you-decide-the-end-of-the-story/. (Stockdale's story was described at length in the podcast.)

Comment: Thanks so much. "Stoic" reveals their qualities but not their status of being workers.

Comment: A *stoic worker* or *stoic laborer* would capture both the status of being a worker and their attitude toward being overworked. If the stoic has *eudaimonia* as Stockdale did, he would have an optimism in the face of difficult circumstances. He said, "I never lost faith in the end of the story, I never doubted not only that I would get out, but also that I would prevail in the end and turn the experience into the defining event of my life, which, in retrospect, I would not trade."

Comment: A stoic isn't optimistic; they're indifferent to their circumstances (although they may try to find personal contentment or peace, they're not looking for any external reward). That's the essential feature of a stoic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very American, for example the smile a woman over the counter at McDonalds gives you when you buy a breakfast McMuffin and when she's on minimum wage (read poverty wages). I'd call it wage slavery. Or ironically, McOptimism (at a McJob).